# Xamarin.Form XamlCompilation error: Value cannot be null, Parameter name: method

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using VS 2015 on Windows 10, Xamarin for VS is latest version updated few day ago, around 02/11/2016

When I add the XAML compilation for namespace in App.cs

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class App:Application{...}
}
```

All my .xaml file build error with message:

```
Value cannot be null 
Parameter name: method
```

Even I create new empty XAML, the error still included.
Anyone experience with this issue and knowing how to fix it.

PS: Purpose to adding this line to try to improve performance

Comment: Can you try to add `[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` above the class definition ?

Comment: If I apply above code for only one class (XMAL class), then that class show error. If I apply both class and namespace, all XAML show error

Comment: Put the line above `public class App:Application{...}`

Comment: App is cs class, don't need to compilation. That what I understand from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Answer (score 0):

After I updated the latest version of Xamarin Form (currently is 3.3.2.1).
This is gone.