# Regressed Issue: XamlCompilation error Value cannot be null, Parameter name: method

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I searched SO to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441858/xamarin-form-xamlcompilation-error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-method) issue, but the answer didn't work for me so the issue still exists.

Personally, I believe the issue is probably related to some configuration "thing", but I would have no idea where to start looking to resolve it. To my knowledge, I have not altered any config settings out of norm (just used standard new project approach). Here is some detail on my issue:

Just so happens that today is first time trying out the XamlC feature. At first I tried the assembly level attribute in my App.cs file:

```cs
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

After compiling, I was getting a bunch of errors that were all identical. I also got a a different error on any page using a TemplateControl. So I pulled it off the assembly level and put a single class-level attribute on one page, and it still failed with the same error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method
```

I poked around on Stackoverflow and found that about a year ago someone had the same issue (here), but they said they resolved it by upgrading Xam Forms to latest version. Since I'm on the latest stable versions, I have no where to go there.

I tried this class-level attribute on several pages in my app and only found it to work on a single page in my entire app... just so happens this page has zero bindings in the XAML markup. I'm wondering if a bug was introduced that causes it to blow up.

Markup of page that doesn't work:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Prepify.App.Pages.MainMenu"
                         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
                         BackgroundColor="White"
             Title="Menu">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView
            Header="{Binding .}"
            SeparatorColor="{StaticResource dividerColor}"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemSelected="AppMenu_OnItemSelected"
            ItemTapped="AppMenu_OnItemTapped"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            x:Name="appMenu">

            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource grayDark}"/>
                        <controls:CircleImage Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="End" Source="{Binding ProfileImageUrl}" WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                        <ActivityIndicator Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="White" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <StackLayout.Padding>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android="15,15,15,15" iOS="25,12,15,12" />
                            </StackLayout.Padding>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"/>
                            <Image WidthRequest="20"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Label}" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{Binding LabelColor}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Markup of only page that does work (note, no bindings anywhere):

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Prepify.App.Pages.Root"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Prepify.App.Pages;assembly=Prepify.App"
    MasterBehavior="Popover"
    Title="Make Preparedness Easy">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:MainMenu/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

I'm using all the latest as of posting this question.
Visual Studio 2015
Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193
Xamarin.VS 4.3.0.784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... after getting your feedback and some from [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89398/is-xamlcompile-broken-in-latest-forms-vs), I just decided to try and rebuild my PCL from scratch. After hours of painstakingly migrating files over one at a time and ensuring the XamlCompilation worked at every step along the way, I got it to work build with no errors. Then I just copied the new projects I had made (2 PCLs) right over top the old ones and the solution compiled perfectly.

Answer: ??? There is none. This was a total fluke. There is nothing I learned along the way that could pinpoint the cause of the issue. If you get this issue, try rebuilding your PCL from scratch using the standard project template.

Comment: You learned, like me and many before me, we made a mistake by using xamarin.

Comment: Just got the same build error pointing to line 1 of all my xaml files. Thankfully this happened on a quick Prism Forms test project. It occurred after adding a ContentPage from the Prism template pack. Tried to build after wiring up navigation to it and got this: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type. On every XAML file in my project.

Comment: Was able to resolve by updating Xamarin.Forms...even though I was showing the latest installed. ??

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue for a project that contains exactly ONE Page (xaml + cs) and ONE ViewModel. I changed one line, saved the chance and it didn't build anymore, also with this error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method
```

In my case changing the package version fixed it. Just right click on your project > open the Properties > open Package Tab on the left > and increase the Package version number. And of course, I did many many Clean and Rebuilds on my Solution.

This is what worked for me, but I have to confess that I just got started with Xamarin, so I dont really know what Im doing :D 
Maybe this is helpful to anyone.

Oh and maybe important to say: Im working with Xamarin 3.2.0.839982 in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I tried a few other solutions that didn't work but this did and it was by far the most simple to try. Simply changed the Package Version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 in the project properties and it rebuilt with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: this isn't a proper answer, but that's too long for a comment. Answer it is then.

I took the XAML you pasted and used it in a new and fresh Xamarin.Forms project (referencing XF 2.3.3.180 (tried with .193 as well) and ImageCircle 1.8.1) stubbed the 2 event handlers, added the `[XamlCompilation]` attribute and it compiles just fine.

If you can't narrow down your issue and still think it's an issue in Xamarin.Forms, you should open a bug report with a reproduction case at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Forms. You can even ping me when it's done so I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by removing all this lines from the PCL project, not sure what is the impact though.

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```